# jQuery copy from Excel to multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I have na excel sheet with the data:

```
English | Spanish | Italian | French
```

I'd like to be able to copy all these inputs and paste it to the form:

```
<input type="text" name="english">
<input type="text" name="spanish">
<input type="text" name="italian">
<input type="text" name="french">
```

so far when I copy all the data it will all paste into first input field.
I'm asking this before I start coding as I'm not sure if it's even possible to do.

Any directions appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon your clarification, you can use jQuery to capture the paste action into anyone of those fields. Then simply parse and send it to the right input box.

### HTML

```
<input type="text" name="english">
<input type="text" name="spanish">
<input type="text" name="italian">
<input type="text" name="french">
```

### jQuery

```
$('input').bind('paste', null, function(e){
    $this = $(this);

    setTimeout(function(){
        var columns = $this.val().split(/\s+/);
        $this.val(' ');
        var i;

        for(i=0; i < columns.length; i++){
            var name = columns[i].toLowerCase();
            $('input[name="' + name + '"]').val(columns[i]);
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

Here's a demo fiddle to look at : http://jsfiddle.net/adjit/3N94L/3/

Comment: this is nice but that's not what I'm looking for. Copy text from the excel sheet and paste into already existing input fields in such a way so the columns go into right input field...

Comment: @Grasper i'm not sure how universal this will be, but its a good start

Answer (score 2):

The clipboard is not going to allow this.   You might want to look into a library like HandsOnTable which will parse the clipboard/excel data and run the paste into multiple inputs.

http://handsontable.com/

Comment: what section talks about it?

Comment: The whole thing is designed to mimic excel.  It turns the 'cells' into individual inputs.  You can then grab that row and parse it on the back end.

Comment: that is nice but I want to be taking data from excel not from the html page that uses excel like features...

Comment: Right, that's exactly what this allows....  this is the main HOT demo:   http://jsfiddle.net/briansol/rKy7z/     in the 4th quadrant, paste in a row you copied from excel and watch what happens...

Comment: @briansol you don't need hacks to use the external resource. There is a tab to add external resources : http://jsfiddle.net/adjit/rKy7z/1/

Comment: Again, that is a direct fork of the HOT example... go here:  http://handsontable.com/  hit the blue Edit on JSFiddle link.