# Copy Excel data to inputs on web form

Tags: jquery, excel

I would like to copy a row of excel data with a couple columns and be able to copy each row and paste into a web form so that each column value from excel gets pasted into each form field input.

Tried using the script suggested here: [jQuery copy from Excel to multiple input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208985/jquery-copy-from-excel-to-multiple-input-fields) but when pasting my data disappears.

**Update**

This almost works, only now its copying the last value into all fields:

```
$('input').bind('paste', null, function(e){
    $this = $(this);

    setTimeout(function(){
        var columns = $this.val().split(/\s+/);
        var i;

        for(i=0; i < columns.length; i++){
            $('input').val(columns[i]);
        }
    }, 0);
});'
```

Answer (score 2):

Managed to find the answer on the JQuery forum: 
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/pasting-from-excel-to-multiple-input-fields

Comment: The code in the link you have shared is working well. I have just changed \s to \t since I have text with space inside a cell and it was splitting the text when pasting.

Answer (score 0):

look something here in the code you shared $this.val(' '); i think there should not be space.HTH