# Copy From My Site, Paste To Other Site. But It's Multiple Data

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an online shop with regular data such as : product name, price, description, etc.

And I want to sell my product to marketplaces such as : ebay, etc.

what is the best way to copy multiple data and paste it at once? Just like Google Chrome autofill. But I need something that programmatically.

I found this : [jQuery copy from Excel to multiple input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208985/jquery-copy-from-excel-to-multiple-input-fields)

but in my case, it's not possible to put jquery on destination site. because that's others people site.

Comment: eBay (and possibly the "etc.") has an API. Otherwise, consider something like writing a Chrome extension.

Comment: @ceejayoz : That's a great idea, bro! I will spend my next few days to learn more about Chrome extension. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do that. Because not every site use the same name for the input elements. For example:

```
Site A:
<input name="item_name">

site B:
<input name="name">
```

So you can't copy paste to multiple site with one code.